# Question when printing color using list in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

```cpp
    int bodyColorFig = 255 / Colornum;
    _GboxColor = 255;
    _BboxColor = 0;
    POSITION traversalNode = _boxes.GetHeadPosition();
    while (traversalNode != nullptr) {
        _bodyPos = _boxes.GetAt(traversalNode);
        _GboxColor -= bodyColorFig;
        _BboxColor += bodyColorFig;
        CBrush brush(RGB(0, _GboxColor, _BboxColor));
        memDc.SelectObject(brush);
        memDc.Rectangle(_bodyPos.x - halfLength, _bodyPos.y - halfLength, _bodyPos.x + halfLength, _bodyPos.y + halfLength);
        _boxes.GetNext(traversalNode);
    }
```

This code is part of the `OnPaint` function in mfc. I'm making a worm game and the color output on the list `_boxes` is something wrong. All other functions related to the worm game work well. But the second list's color representation on the worm's head is strange as soon as it eats. The variable `Colornum` is initialized to 1, and the value increases by 1 when the head of the worm is equal to the position of the prey. I want to modify it so that the blue color that appears briefly as soon as the worm eats food no longer appears, but I don't know the cause. The same phenomenon occurs when the `bodyColorFig` value, which sets the values of `_BboxColor` and `_GboxColor`, is declared outside the `OnPaint` function. Why is this happening?

This is what I made.

[image]

Comment: You were given helpful links to references that introduce you to using a debugger. Why did you decide to delete that question? Why did you decide against using a debugger?

Comment: It this for real? I didn't see any comments. I'm sorry. I just wanted to change the question more intuitively.

Comment: The question you decided to delete, along with all the helpful comments it got. A link to an article that explains how to debug simple programs. Deleting a question is a destructive process.